# React Polyfills: react-app-rewired making crypto/crypto-browserify get imported outside of src

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, polyfills, react-app-rewired

I am getting this error:

> Module not found: Error: You attempted to import
> /my-project/node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js which falls
> outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of
> src/ are not supported.

I need to use the `crypto` library which is no longer autoincluded. I followed the `react-app-rewired` instructions to override this dependency, and instead use `crypto-browserify`, but then this error shows up.

This is an excerpt of my `config-overrides.js` file:

```
Object.assign(fallback, {
    crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    assert: require.resolve("assert"),
    http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
    https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
    os: require.resolve("os-browserify"),
    url: require.resolve("url"),
  });
```

I haven't been able to find an answer to this problem yet.
Any idea how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Relevant Dependencies:
react: "^18.2.0"
crypto-browserify: "^3.12.0"
react-scripts: "5.0.1"
react-app-rewired: "^2.2.1" - // As dev dependency

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?